# Can I use "so" in place of "so that" without losing the meaning of the sentence?

Tags: comparison

I'm thinking if I "so" can be sometimes used instead of "so that" without losing the meaning of the sentence.

For example:

> Can you register me for it **SO THAT** I could access the blackboard
>
> Can you register me for it **SO** I could access the blackboard

To my ear both forms sound pretty good, but as English is not my native tongue, I could be wrong.

Comment: I would have said that "so that" was the 'basic' form in purpose adjuncts like this one. Nevertheless "that" is readily omissible, and according to the graph I looked at, that alternant is more frequent. But both are fine.

Answer (score 1):

'So that' is a more formal and archaic form.  'So' by itself is the much more commonly used form, and has the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The word "that", used as a CONJUNCTION, is frequently omitted from informal speech. (Depending on context "that" can also be used as a PRONOUN, ADVERB, ADJECTIVE or DEFINITE ARTICLE.)

Thus "that" is often left out of such sentences as: "He said that he felt ill."

In your examples, while the meaning of the second sentence is clear, the first sentence (including the word "that") is preferable.